# Using enaml to create UI binding to string in textfile

Tags: python, user-interface, enaml

I want to use a custom markup to generate a GUI in enaml.
Is it possible to bind variables from the input form to a text file?

Sample Input:
**template.ml**

```
!MENUBAR
 !ITEM TEXT="NEW FILE"  ACTION="emacs -nw {{textinput}}" FORM=(@textinput@|"new document.txt")!END
!END
```

`new document.txt` is supposed to be a default value.

Is it possible to use enaml like this?